# weird typeerror when i use pd.assign function

Tags: python, pandas

So i have the code below which is supposed to get a dataset, interpolate it to 100 datapoints, add another column of 1,2,....100 and then differentiate it to target and training for a NN. so the code is:

```
#initiate path of datafile
path = r'C:\Users\xatzo\LocalDisk\Data'  

#put all files together
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))# advisable to use os.path.join,make concatenation OSindependent

#specify the length for interpolation
new_length = 100

#dataframes final
dataframes=[]
targets=[]

#array of timesteps
timestep=[]
for i in range(100):
    timestep.append(i+1)



for f in all_files:
    df= pd.read_csv(f)
    #drop bad columns
    df=df.drop(df.columns[[0,14,15,19,24,25,29,36]], axis=1)
    #interpolation
    x = np.array(range(0,len(df)))
    y = df.values
    new_x = np.linspace(0, len(df)-1, new_length)
    kin = pd.DataFrame(sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, axis=0, kind='quadratic')(new_x),columns=df.columns)
    print(len(kin))
    print(len(timestep))
    #add axis of time
    df=df.assign(timestep)
    #creating target and training
    kin_target=kin.columns[[26,27,28]]
    kin_input=kin.drop(df.columns[[26,27,28]],axis=1)
    #print(kin)
    dataframes.append(kin_input)
```

but when i run it i get this:

```
100
100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-e71b2f86df57> in <module>
     31     print(len(timestep))
     32     #add axis of time
---> 33     df=df.assign(timestep)
     34     #creating target and training
     35     kin_target=kin.columns[[26,27,28]]

TypeError: assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

which is very weird because they have the same length according to what i have done.
Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I think you need to specify a column name for assign. So try ```df=df.assign(column_name=timestep)```.

Comment: i get a new error : 'ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index'

Comment: the len of added value need to match the number of rows

Comment: i t does, as you can see on the output i get 100 as both len outputs